# How to transpose mysql table data using mysql query

Tags: mysql, transpose

I would like to transpose attendance sql table as below

[image: Below Mysql table data]

To the following

[image]

Please help me here

Thanks
Sara

Comment: So what have you tried? **SO != Free coding resource**

Comment: Thats itself a subquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select pname,
       sum(case when weekday = 'Monday' then days else 0 end) as M,
       . . .,
       sum(days) as Total
from  t
group by pname;
```

Put the logic in the for the rest of the weekdays where `. . .` is.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, this solved and helped me in time